# like operator in entitydatasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sql-like, entitydatasource, entity-sql

I'm using an EntityDataSource in an asp .net form and a Gridview is bound to it.  A where clause is used in the entityDataSource:

```
Where="it.Name like '%@Name%'
```

`@Name` is a parameter:

```
<WhereParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"  />
</WhereParameters>
```

But it doesn't work.  When I change `@Name` with a fixed string it works properly, like this:

```
Where="it.Name like '%ppp%'"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Where="it.Name like '%' + @Name+ '%'"
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful - Thanks. Comment from @fubo is also great

Answer (score 2):

A empty `TextBox` should force the `EntityDataSource` to show all elements

```
Where="it.Name like '%' + @Name + '%' OR @Name IS NULL"
```

Comment: Down to requirements but yes, in my case this is exactly what i needed!